# Calculate fruit yield year-on-year, given yield at maturity and time to first fruiting?

Tags: fruit-trees, fruits

I'm putting together a plan for a fruit wine business, and need to calculate expected yields for fruit trees each year from the date of planting. I have found various resources that provide 'time to first fruiting' and 'yield at maturity', but rarely can I find information stating the *yield at first fruiting* or *time to maturity*. Without these pieces of information, it is impossible to estimate expected yield from year to year.

For my business plan, I need to calculate the yield of various plants from the year of planting until year 5. These will be for specific cultivars, and to give some context, I am interested in Blackberry, Damson, Elderberry (and Elderflower), Nettle and Rhubarb.

**I am aware of how hopelessly imprecise any such calculations would be**; locality and climate clearly have a huge impact. Nevertheless, this is a bureaucratic exercise I need to go through; I have to provide estimated figures for a business plan. Given the information available from most sources (**time to fruiting** and **yield at maturity**), how do I go about calculating an expected yield for years 1 to 5?

Comment: you are unlikely to get any yield at all in years 1-2 and very little if any in years 3-4  for the elderberry and damson; damson yield will also be dependent on a suitable tree in the right pollination group being planted nearby https://www.ashridgetrees.co.uk/gardening-advice/fruit-tree-advice/pollinating-plum-trees